# Android: ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams not working

Tags: android, android-layoutparams

I used this to set the margin programmatically, but it does not work, the margins are not applied. In the constructor:

```
public TimeWindow(Context context, int pixels, int left, int top){
    super(context);
    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(pixels, pixels);
    params.setMargins(left, top, 0, 0);
    this.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Comment: Try getting the existing layout param of the view and set the margin for that.

Comment: @Triode thank you for the reply. I tried to get the params. But it seems that the params is null when I tried to get them. Maybe because this code is in the constructor of a custom view object.

Comment: I'd imagine they could be null if the views haven't been laid out yet (if the above is in a view constructor).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deducing from your comments, you're setting your params when your `View` does not have `LayoutParams` yet, and they are being overwritten when you attach your `View` to the layout. What I would advice you to do is to move the setting of your `LayoutParams` to the `onAttachedToWindow` method. Then you will be able to obtain `LayoutParams` with `getLayoutParams()` and modify them.

```
private final int mPixelSize;
private final int mLeftMargin;
private final int mTopMargin;

public TimeWindow(Context context, int pixels, int left, int top){
    super(context);
    mPixelSize = pixels;
    mLeftMargin = left;
    mTopMargin = top;
}

@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    if (getLayoutParams() instanceof MarginLayoutParams){ 
        //if getLayoutParams() returns null, the if condition will be false
        MarginLayoutParams layoutParams = (MarginLayoutParams) getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.width = mPixelSize;
        layoutParams.height = mPixelSize;
        layoutParams.setMargins(mLeftMargin, mTopMargin, 0, 0);
        requestLayout();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace MarginLayoutParams with this LayoutParams as :

```
 LayoutParams params= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( pixels, pixels);
params.setMargins(left, top, 0, 0);
this.setLayoutParams(params);
```

you have to replace LinearLayout.LayoutParams with your layout on which you are working on. Hope it will work

Comment: Thank you. I knew that sollution, but that requires API 11, mine is API 9.

Comment: i think LinearLayout.LayoutParams is added in Api Level 1 it will work fine in your case too.

Comment: The problem is I cannot use LinearLayout.